# How to pass values from datasets back to main report?

Tags: jasper-reports

**Problem:**

I have composite `JRXML` report. Composite report contains many charts. Each chart is assigned to some dataset. I need to pass the variables/parameters values back to main report from datasets?

**Tried:**

I tried `scriptlets`, `customizers` but they are all scoped to the `dataset` to which they are assigned and cannot see or change the `parameters` of the main report.

Global `scriptlets` do not have knowledge about `dataset parameters`(to be precise they do not know their values and they can't assign their values, they only can find out their description and names via usage of `JASPER_REPORT` parameter which has mainly lookup functionallity).

This poses a fundamental problem for me as I can't aggregate values in one place as I can't extract them from each individual dataset.

**Context problem:**

The reason I need to do this because Jasper reports design is flawed for one fundamental requirement: "consistent colours" across all the charts in the composite report. So if you have "China" in Pie Chart and it has colour GREEN and you also have Bar Chart having different query but returning some values which exist in Pie Chart - you'd want the China to have GREEN colour in Bar Chart too.

**Approach to context problem:**

For this task you need to exctract all the field values from each dataset and save them in main report parameter. You then have to assign each value to some color value and check aggregate main report parameter inside customizers whether current value has a color assigned. This is at least my plan. For this task I need to be able to get back data from datasets generated by their local queries. But I am limited by the scope of datasets as they work only on input data not output data.